# ColdFusion 10 upgrade 14 - scheduled tasks always using a proxy for 127.0.0.1 jobs

Tags: coldfusion, proxy, iis-7.5

We manually upgraded our Enterprise version of ColdFusion 10 server to upgrade 14 on our Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.  As recommended by Adobe for this upgrade, we installed the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable 2012 update 4, installed the ColdFusion upgrade 14 jar file (run as an administrator from the command prompt) and followed up with running wsconfig (run as administrator) to drop and add the connections.

We noticed that after the upgrade was installed that our scheduled jobs are not successfully running using 127.0.0.1. We sent the output of the scheduled tasks to a text file and the file indicates that access is denied.  It appears that all the scheduled tasks are going through a proxy. We would like to know how to set up the scheduled tasks to bypass this proxy.

We’ve attempted to run it as localhost and the actual URL – none of which succeed. If we take the 127.0.0.1 URL and run it on the server using Internet Explorer 10, it runs without any issues. It only fails when run through ColdFusion scheduled tasks. The following is the information that is displayed in the text file:

**ERROR**

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http: //127.0.0.1/Test.cfm
Access Denied.
Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.
Your cache administrator is XXX@mysite.com.

Generated Thu, 04 Dec 2014 13:28:25 GMT by proxy.XXX.com (squid/3.1.10)

Comment: Barry, what makes you think it is running through a proxy? is it the "cache administrator" line? A proxy is an unlikely problem if you are using 127.0.0.1 - such a proxy would have to be running ON the server - surely something you would know about. Did you re-run the connector script for the IIS/Apache site that is serving 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Wait... I see the note on squid - did you add that? Are you perhaps using squid as a reverse proxy?

Comment: I guess you must have resolved this then :)

Comment: Mark - there is no reverse proxy set up. when the task runs through the ColdFusion Scheduled tasks, it is somehow forced to go through a proxy server. I'm trying to locate how this can be prevented from happening. It's either a CF issue or something with IIS, but I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: if you are hitting 127.0.0.1 then you almost _have_ to have an agent running _on_ the server intercepting outgoing calls. I can't think of another way to co-opt that address. A typical local proxy will forward all outgoing HTTP to the loopback address then proxy it. If you were using an external proxy then you would not have this problem - because the javax.inet (or apache http) client would not automatically forward to a proxy - clear as mud I know (ha)>